# Python Square function using newton's algorithm

Tags: python, math

how to create a python function called mySqrt that will approximate the square root of a number, call it n, by using Newton’s algorithm. Here's what I tried so far:

```
def newguess(x):
    result = x/2
    return result

def mySqrt(n):
    result = (1/2) * (oldguess + (n/oldguess))
    return result

v = newguess(45)
t = mySqrt(65)
print(t)
```

Comment: what is `oldguess`? and when is `newguess()` ever used? and remember to put `x/2.0` or else integer division will happen.

Comment: That's what's the assignment said to include. I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def my_sqrt(n):
    approx = n/2
    closer = (approx + n/approx)/2
    while closer != approx:
        approx = closer
        closer = (approx + n/approx)/2
    return approx
```

Answer (score 1):

The Newton method finds an approximated solution `r` of the equation `f(x) = 0` as follows:

1. **[Initialize]** Set `r` to some initial guess. Set `epsilon := 0.00001` (precision)
2. **[Iterate]** While `abs(f(r)) > epsilon` Repeat `r := r - f(r)/f'(r)`
3. **[End]** Return `r`

In step 1 above, `epsilon` is the precision you want to achieve. The larger the precision the longer your program will take. In step 2 `f'(r)` stands for the derivative of `f` at `r`.

Now, you want to compute `sqrt(a)` for any value of `a >= 0` using the Newton method.

By definition `x = sqrt(a)` means `x^2 = a` or `x^2 - a = 0`. Let `f(x) = x^2 - a.` Finding a solution `r` of `f(x) = 0` is equivalent to finding `r = sqrt(a)`. Note that in this case we have `f'(x) = 2*x.`

If we now apply the above algorithm to this case with `a/2` as the initial guess (actually anything between `0` and `a`), we get:

1. **[Initialize]** Set `r := a/2` and `epsilon := 0.000000001`
2. **[Iterate]** While `abs(r^2 - a) > epsilon` Repeat `r := r - (r^2 - a)/(2*r)`
3. **[End]** Return `r`

So, the only you have to do now is to translate these three simple steps into a phyton program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses 50 iterations to approximate the value:

```
def mySqrt(n):
newGuess=n/2
for i in range(50):
    newGuess=0.5*(newGuess + (n/newGuess))
return newGuess
```